# Does php recursively execute itself?

Tags: php, apache, security

I have a simple question. If I write a php file that will result in echoing another correct php statement, will this be executed? For instance:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php echo "hello: "."<?php echo '1';?>"; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Will this ever produce the output: `Hello: 1` ?

I would have said no, but if I run this under Apache, the "inner echo" gets "sanitized" as `<!--?php echo '1';?-->`, which leads me to believe it could.

Thanks!

Comment: No, it doesn't, it's just another level of security.

Comment: your inner "<?php echo '1';?>" is contained inside another PHP block and will be treated as a string so no, it should never give you `Hello: 1`, except you would eval() the inner statement. I *assume* Apache cleans the `<?` to avoid confusion with inline XML contents also starting with `<?`

Comment: Your web server must be interfering with your PHP file. The string `"<?php echo '1';?>"` is just that, a string - and should be printed to the screen verbatim (since it contains angle brackets you'll need to view-source to see it in a browser).

Comment: Your server must be really messed up ... PHP does not execute itself see http://3v4l.org/kd7qf

Comment: Thanks all. I think @SaschaM78 's assumption makes sense; I could not understand why Apache would sanitize something like that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks God it doesn't. In order to execute a string you should (**not**) use `eval()`:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php echo "hello: ".eval("echo '1';"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code is incorrect, it must be eval("echo '1';"); and yes, eval is evil

Comment: Yep, @m4t1t0 is right. Jeffrey, pls correct so I can accept the answer. Btw, I'm not planning on doing anything crazy like that :) Just was wondering why Apache would do that. I came to this investigating how could a "PHP Injection" in something like a UA/Referer ever work, unless of course PHP would for some strange reason re-execute itself.